# Is it possible to Team 2 static IPs over 1 DSL

Tags: networking, dsl

I have a single DSL line with a block of 8 (5 usable) static IPs.  I want to know if it is possible to team 2 or 3 of the IPs and if so, will it help with my upload/download rate or is the up/down rate a limit of the copper?

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question. Multiple IPs give you additional service capability and some redundancy, not extra bandwidth.

Comment: There isn't anything you can do to change the capacity or latency of the connection but if you could multiplex an active upload/download session across multiple ip addresses then it could reduce the time taken to upload/download by virtue of uploading/downloading the data in multiple streams. That's in theory, not in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice your bandwidth is limited by a [packet shaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) at your ISP so using more IP's will not get you additional bandwidth.

Theoretically, if you get into the inner workings of TCP, you will probably even *lose* effective bandwidth by using multiple IP's because the TCP window size will be reduced if you are running multiple TCP sessions (you would need at least a single TCP session per IP). Thus you would lose more bandwidth on TCP overhead.